# How to convert string to number in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of objects which has an array inside an
array. the values are in the string, I want it to be a number. What is
the best possible solution to do that in JavaScript.

```
[
    {
        "key": "America",
        "values": [
            [
                "1469664000000",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "1469750400000",
                "13"
            ],
            [
                "1469836800000",
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "1469923200000",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "1470009600000",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "1470096000000",
                "1"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "India",
        "values": [
            [
                "1469750400000",
                "1"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "China",
        "values": [
            [
                "1469664000000",
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "1469836800000",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "1470096000000",
                "12"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "Africa",
        "values": [
            [
                "1470096000000",
                "1"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "UK",
        "values": [
            [
                "1469664000000",
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "1469750400000",
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "1469836800000",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "1469923200000",
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "1470009600000",
                "4"
            ],
            [
                "1470096000000",
                "2"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: iterate over the array and `parseInt(str,10)` every number.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var data = [{"key":"America","values":[["1469664000000","1"],["1469750400000","13"],["1469836800000","2"],["1469923200000","1"],["1470009600000","1"],["1470096000000","1"]]},{"key":"India","values":[["1469750400000","1"]]},{"key":"China","values":[["1469664000000","2"],["1469836800000","1"],["1470096000000","12"]]},{"key":"Africa","values":[["1470096000000","1"]]},{"key":"UK","values":[["1469664000000","3"],["1469750400000","3"],["1469836800000","1"],["1469923200000","2"],["1470009600000","4"],["1470096000000","2"]]}];

data.forEach(function (o) {
  o.values.forEach(function (values) {
    values.forEach(function (value, i) {
      values[i] = parseInt(value, 10);
    });
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Comment: parseInt without radix? :)

Comment: `parseInt(value, 10)`

Comment: @naveen Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{"key":"America","values":[["1469664000000","1"],["1469750400000","13"],["1469836800000","2"],["1469923200000","1"],["1470009600000","1"],["1470096000000","1"]]},{"key":"India","values":[["1469750400000","1"]]},{"key":"China","values":[["1469664000000","2"],["1469836800000","1"],["1470096000000","12"]]},{"key":"Africa","values":[["1470096000000","1"]]},{"key":"UK","values":[["1469664000000","3"],["1469750400000","3"],["1469836800000","1"],["1469923200000","2"],["1470009600000","4"],["1470096000000","2"]]}];

 data = data.map(function(t){
    var newVals = t.values.map(function(vs){
      return vs.map(function(v){
        return parseInt(v, 10);
     });
    });
    return {'key': t.key, values: newVals};
 });
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.parse(your json object
or maybe use two forEachs

Comment: I don't think you know what `JSON.parse` does. And *"use two for eachs"* is broad and doesn't really answer anything.